# Python Random Values with a Given Density

Tags: python, probability

Say I want to build a maze with a certain probability of an obstacle at each position. This probability is determined by a density value ranging from 0 to 10, with 0 meaning "no chance", and 10 meaning "certain".

Does this Python code do what I want?

```
import random

obstacle_density = 10
if random.randint(0, 9) < obstacle_density:
    print("There is an obstacle")
```

I've tried various combinations of upper and lower bounds and inequalities, and this seems to do the job, but I'm suspicious. For one thing, 11 possible values for `obstacle_density` and only 10 in `random.randint(0, 9)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "11 possible values for `obstacle_density`"? You defined `obstacle_density = 10`, so there is *one* possible value, which is 10.

Comment: I thought the question wording would make it clear that the variable could be assigned values from 0 - 10 inclusive, hence 11 possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Not super sure about your solution. It seems like it would work, though.
Here's how I would approach it, even if it is a bit redundant - I'd start with a table just for my own reference:

```
density | probability of obstacle
---------------------------------
 0      |   0%
 1      |  10%
 2      |  20%
 3      |  30%
 4      |  40%
 5      |  50%
 6      |  60%
 7      |  70%
 8      |  80%
 9      |  90%
10      | 100%
```

This seems to add up. I present two versions of a function which returns `True` or `False` depending on the `density`. In the first version, I use the `density` to create the associated weights to be used with `random.choices` (the total weight in this case would be 100). For example, if `density = 3`, then `weights = [30, 70]` - 30% to be `True`, 70% to be `False`.

```
def get_obstacle_state_version_1(density):
    from random import choices

    assert isinstance(density, int)
    assert density in range(0, 11) # 0 - 10 inclusive

    true_weight = density * 10
    false_weight = 100 - true_weight

    weights = [true_weight, false_weight]

    return choices([True, False], weights=weights, k=1)[0]
```

Here's the second version, in which I use `random.choice` rather than `random.choices`. The latter always returns a list of samples, even if the sample size `k` is 1.
Here, the idea is the same, but basically the density influences the number of `True`s and `False`s that appear in the population to be sampled. For example, if `density = 3`, then `random.choice` would pick one element from a list of 30 `True`s, and 70 `False`s with a uniform distribution.

```
def get_obstacle_state_version_2(density):
    from random import choice

    assert isinstance(density, int)
    assert density in range(0, 11) # 0 - 10 inclusive

    true_count = density * 10
    false_count = 100 - true_count

    return choice([True] * true_count + [False] * false_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the maze and at each site assign a probability. 
You should do something like this:

```
probability = random.randint(0, 10) / 10
```

I have no idea what you mean by `obstacle_density`, so I am not gonna go there.